# Как менять значение поля относительно значения другого поля в Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеется проект на Laravel. Есть два поля.

Первое поле - количество участников.

Второе - сумма на одного участника.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="model.amount_users">
<input type="text" ng-model="model.price">
```

Передо мной стоит задача при при создании и редактировании через эту форму делить общую сумму на количество участников и записывать это значение во второе поле.

Общая сумма выводится во view через `{{$game->price}}`.

Куда записать общую сумму и как манипулировать вторым полем?

Comment: `$game->price` Это серверная переменная?

Comment: $game - это массив, который передаётся во вьюху из контроллера.

Comment: Вьюха и контроллер, где расположены - на сервере? В Angular тоже есть понятие controller и view. Данная конструкция `{{$game->price}}` смахивает на шаблонизатор Blade, используемый в Laravel. В ответе, который представлен ниже подставляете вашу переменную `ng-init="total_price={{$game->price}}"`.

Comment: Вы, случаем, не родственник Маврина? :)

Answer (score 1):

Все серверные переменные, которые являются глобальными по отношению к клиенту лучше всего указывать где-нибудь в заголовке страницы (`<body>` или `<html>`) через [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Смотрите результат:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    if ($scope.amount_users) {
      $scope.average_price = $scope.total_price / $scope.amount_users;
    }
  };
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-init="total_price=20" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="submit($event)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="total_price" placeholder="total_price">
    <input type="text" ng-model="amount_users" placeholder="amout users">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  Average price: <span ng-bind="average_price"></span>
</div>
```